# Present Continuous or Present Simple in a Meeting

Tags: future, present-tense, will-be-going

Which one of the following should be used if I am asking about an event or a meeting:

> 1. Are we meeting today?
> 2. Do we have a meeting today?
> 3. Are we going to have a meeting today?
> 4. Are we going to meet today?
> 5. Will we have a meeting today?

Comment: How would we know? We cannot guess how you would like to put it depending on the context. Each version is acceptable in its own way.

Answer (score 3):

All are grammatical. The choice depends on the precise context in which you are seeking the information, but *Are we going to have a meeting today?* is likely to cover most situations.

Comment: What could those contexts be?

Comment: @Mohammad: Almost infinite! Describe in as much detail as you can the context you yourself have in mind. Who might you be speaking to? Why are you asking the question? Is the meeting a regular one?

Comment: Thanks, but say the meeting is not a regular one. In that case can I say: Are we meeting today? And if the meeting is a regular one, can I still use the same tense?

Comment: As well as the almost infinite number of contexts, there are an almost infinite number of phrasings. *Do we meet today? Is the meeting today? Will we meet today?* etc., etc. I'm in rant mode today, so I may overstate the case - but to a considerable extent they're all simply equivalents, with little chance that any distinction will be either intended or understood by the choice of one over another.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To say nothing of the tone of voice in which each might be said and the gestures and facial expressions that might accompany them.

Comment: Then we'd have a *third* infinite number to deal with! It's a good job we're not on math.se or philosophy.se I gather they don't even like multiplying entities unnecessarily, let alone infinities! But seriously, without special typography, tone of voice, or non-verbal cues, it's not obvious to me that any of these variants would inherently convey any difference in meaning to any others.