# Present Simple vs Present Continuous for future actions

Tags: present-tense, present-progressive

I know we can use both Present Simple and Present Continuous to describe future actions. But I don't know when to use the correct form.

For example:

We fly to Paris next week.

We are flying to Paris next week.

These sentences both seem correct to me. 
Can anyone explain me how to correctly use these tenses?

Comment: related: [Present Continuous or Present Simple in a Meeting](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54831/present-continuous-or-present-simple-in-a-meeting) and [Present tense for future events](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29141/present-tense-for-future-events)

Comment: The duplicate has been edited to 'Is it correct to say "We start tomorrow"? Shouldn't it be "We are starting tomorrow"? (present simple vs continuous for future event)' as this replicates the body question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning and the sentences are entirely interchangeable, but which is used **can** depend on context. The form of verb in these sentences would normally match that of the question which elicited them.

> Our world tour starts soon. It's going to take three years.
>   Ooh. When **do you go**?
>   We **fly** to Paris next week.

> When **are you going** on holiday?
>   **We are flying** to Paris next week.

It would be unusual (though unremarkable) to mix the replies and use a form which does not match the question.

If there isn't a question to answer, then the simple present is more perfunctory and formal, and the present continuous more informal and conversational.

Answer (score 0):

In normal usages, both your sentences are equivalent. That is, anyone hearing or reading either one of them would gather from each the same information.

The adverbial phrase "next week" sets each sentence into the future leaving little difference between your use of the simple present or the present continuous. Perhaps others on this site can point out a fine distinction between the two in this case, but I know of none.